# How to make the tabBarItem Image appear small and at the same time not let it get pixelated?

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbaritem

I am trying to find the ideal resolution for a tabBarItem image. 
I want to keep the image small and not let it pixelate. I tried decreasing the resolution but the image became pixelated.
I tried resolution of 60x60. The tabBarItem image had clarity but the image  occupied most of the tabBar. 
I tried resolution of 30x30. The image rendered was of the ideal size but the image was pixelated.
 What can I do to to achieve small image rendering on the tabBarItem and simultaneously stop it from getting pixelated ?

Comment: You should use image with same size that you are using in tabBarItem.

Comment: I am using the default tabBarItemSize though I don't know how much that is

Comment: Check my answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use image with same size that you are using in tabBarItem. You can refer [Apple human interface guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/IconMatrix.html) for different image sizes you should use.

Hope this will help :)